# Echoing Integers Using an Array with Java

Tags: java, arrays, integer, echo

I'm working to create a program that takes in 5 `integers` via user input, separated by spaces on the same line. From there I need to assign these integers to an `array` and then echo the `array` back.

Should be pretty straightforward, but I am having a tough time where my echo back is not inserting spaces between the integers i.e, the users input is `{1 2 3 4 5}` and the result is `12345`, which should ideally be `{1 2 3 4 5}`.

This is my first opportunity to play with `arrays`, so any assistance would be helpful!

Below is the code I have written thus far:

```
package echo5ints;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author laure
 */
public class U7D1_Echo5Ints {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i =0;
    int arr[]=new int[5];

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter 5 numbers: ");

    String line = input.nextLine();
    Scanner numbers = new Scanner(line);

    for(i=0;i<5;i++) 
        arr[i]=numbers.nextInt();

    System.out.println("These were the 5 numbers entered: " + arr[0] + arr[1]  + arr[2]  + arr[3]  + arr[4] );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `split` instead and `printf`

```
System.out.print("Please enter 5 numbers: ");
String line = input.nextLine();
String [] arr = line.split (" ");
System.out.printf("These were the 5 numbers entered: %s %s %s %s %s", 
              arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4] );
```

Answer (score 0):

The spaces you seems to have added is for code and not for print statements.

Printf only print what appears inside quotes or the values held by variables.

SO your print line should be

```
  System.out.println("These were the 5 numbers entered: " + arr[0] +" "+ arr[1] +" " + arr[2] +" " + arr[3] +" " + arr[4] );
```